# How mass set up an custom customer attribute?

Tags: php, mysql

Check this out:
[image]

I have two custom customer attributes: `sms_promo` and `sms_on_order_change`. Both have values only with `0` or `1`.

My question is how for example i can set for all customers `sms_promo` to be `1` and `sms_on_order_change` to be `0` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of loading the entire customer collection, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157307/change-category-attribute-within-installation-script to update your attribute and assign a default value to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set all custome attribuite value to all customer

Create new `yourfile.php` file in Magento **Root Folder**

```
<?php
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('');
    $customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

    foreach($customers as $customer){
        $currentCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
        $currentCustomer->setSmsPromo(1);
        $currentCustomer->setSmsOnOrderChange(0);
        $currentCustomer->save();
    }
?>
```

Then run it on brower by load the following url *www.domain.com/yourfile.php*

Comment: When you have for example 100.000 customer you will get php memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/sql/your_customattribute_setup/install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customattribute",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Custom Attribute",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Custom Attribute"));
      $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customattribute");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'customattribute',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
//$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100);
        $attribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/etc/config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
        <global>

            <resources>
                <Your_Customattribute_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Your_Customattribute</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_setup>
                <Your_Customattribute_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_write>
                <Your_Customattribute_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_read>
            </resources>
        </global>

    </config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Your_Customattribute.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Then to retrieve or edit you use:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
$customer->getCustomattribute();
$customer->setCustomattribute($yourjson);
```